How to merge every three lines into one line from the command line?
We have text file in below format. We need to merge three lines into singles. I tried some Unix command but it is not giving fruitful result.
sed -n '/TitanBalance/{
N
s/\n/ /p
}' Titaninput.txt

Text content:
<TitanBalance releaseID="9999.999" languageCode="en" xmlns="www.titan.com" xmlns:ns="www.titan.org"><ns:ApplicationArea><ns:Sender><ns:LogicalID>ATG</ns:LogicalID><ns:ComponentID>0.0.1.1</ns:ComponentID></ns:Sender><ns:CreationDateTime>2024-05-16T09:26:02.378+02:00</ns:CreationDateTime><ns:DAD>556666660000</ns:DAD></ns:ApplicationArea><DataArea><ns:Process><ns:ActionList><ns:actionFile expressionLanguage="text" actionCode="Modified">supplier</ns:actionFile></ns:ActionList></ns:Process>
<suppementaryBalance><ProductItem><ns:ItemID><ns:ID>000000000101090593</ns:ID></ns:ItemID><ns:UOMCode>EA</ns:UOMCode></ProductItem><ns:supplierdQuantity>1</ns:supplierdQuantity><ns:SalesOrderReference><ns:DocumentID><ns:ID>6666666666666</ns:ID></ns:DocumentID><ns:LineNumber>1</ns:LineNumber></ns:SalesOrderReference><companycode>1488</companycode><ns:Type>Standard</ns:Type><FulfilmentSourceType>new arrival</FulfilmentSourceType></suppementaryBalance>
</DataArea></TitanBalance>

<TitanBalance releaseID="9999.999" languageCode="en" xmlns="www.titan.com" xmlns:ns="www.titan.org"><ns:ApplicationArea><ns:Sender><ns:LogicalID>ATG</ns:LogicalID><ns:ComponentID>0.0.1.1</ns:ComponentID></ns:Sender><ns:CreationDateTime>2024-05-16T09:26:02.378+02:00</ns:CreationDateTime><ns:DAD>556666660000</ns:DAD></ns:ApplicationArea><DataArea><ns:Process><ns:ActionList><ns:actionFile expressionLanguage="text" actionCode="Modified">supplier</ns:actionFile></ns:ActionList></ns:Process>
<suppementaryBalance><ProductItem><ns:ItemID><ns:ID>000000000100007893</ns:ID></ns:ItemID><ns:UOMCode>EA</ns:UOMCode></ProductItem><ns:supplierdQuantity>1</ns:supplierdQuantity><ns:SalesOrderReference><ns:DocumentID><ns:ID>88888888888888</ns:ID></ns:DocumentID><ns:LineNumber>3</ns:LineNumber></ns:SalesOrderReference><companycode>1488</companycode><ns:Type>Standard</ns:Type><FulfilmentSourceType>new arrival</FulfilmentSourceType></suppementaryBalance>
</DataArea></TitanBalance>

<TitanBalance releaseID="9999.999" languageCode="en" xmlns="www.titan.com" xmlns:ns="www.titan.org"><ns:ApplicationArea><ns:Sender><ns:LogicalID>ATG</ns:LogicalID><ns:ComponentID>0.0.1.1</ns:ComponentID></ns:Sender><ns:CreationDateTime>2024-05-16T09:26:02.378+02:00</ns:CreationDateTime><ns:DAD>556666660000</ns:DAD></ns:ApplicationArea><DataArea><ns:Process><ns:ActionList><ns:actionFile expressionLanguage="text" actionCode="Modified">supplier</ns:actionFile></ns:ActionList></ns:Process>
<suppementaryBalance><ProductItem><ns:ItemID><ns:ID>000000000100679537</ns:ID></ns:ItemID><ns:UOMCode>EA</ns:UOMCode></ProductItem><ns:supplierdQuantity>100</ns:supplierdQuantity><ns:SalesOrderReference><ns:DocumentID><ns:ID>00000000000</ns:ID></ns:DocumentID><ns:LineNumber>1</ns:LineNumber></ns:SalesOrderReference><companycode>1484</companycode><ns:Type>Standard</ns:Type><FulfilmentSourceType>new arrival</FulfilmentSourceType></suppementaryBalance>
</DataArea></TitanBalance>

<TitanBalance releaseID="9999.999" languageCode="en" xmlns="www.titan.com" xmlns:ns="www.titan.org"><ns:ApplicationArea><ns:Sender><ns:LogicalID>ATG</ns:LogicalID><ns:ComponentID>0.0.1.1</ns:ComponentID></ns:Sender><ns:CreationDateTime>2024-05-16T09:26:02.378+02:00</ns:CreationDateTime><ns:DAD>556666660000</ns:DAD></ns:ApplicationArea><DataArea><ns:Process><ns:ActionList><ns:actionFile expressionLanguage="text" actionCode="Modified">supplier</ns:actionFile></ns:ActionList></ns:Process>
<suppementaryBalance><ProductItem><ns:ItemID><ns:ID>000000000100663093</ns:ID></ns:ItemID><ns:UOMCode>EA</ns:UOMCode></ProductItem><ns:supplierdQuantity>19</ns:supplierdQuantity><ns:SalesOrderReference><ns:DocumentID><ns:ID>00000000000000</ns:ID></ns:DocumentID><ns:LineNumber>2</ns:LineNumber></ns:SalesOrderReference><companycode>1484</companycode><ns:Type>Standard</ns:Type><FulfilmentSourceType>new arrival</FulfilmentSourceType></suppementaryBalance>
</DataArea></TitanBalance>

<TitanBalance releaseID="9999.999" languageCode="en" xmlns="www.titan.com" xmlns:ns="www.titan.org"><ns:ApplicationArea><ns:Sender><ns:LogicalID>ATG</ns:LogicalID><ns:ComponentID>0.0.1.1</ns:ComponentID></ns:Sender><ns:CreationDateTime>2024-05-16T09:26:02.378+02:00</ns:CreationDateTime><ns:DAD>556666660000</ns:DAD></ns:ApplicationArea><DataArea><ns:Process><ns:ActionList><ns:actionFile expressionLanguage="text" actionCode="Modified">supplier</ns:actionFile></ns:ActionList></ns:Process>
<suppementaryBalance><ProductItem><ns:ItemID><ns:ID>000000000101394699</ns:ID></ns:ItemID><ns:UOMCode>EA</ns:UOMCode></ProductItem><ns:supplierdQuantity>2</ns:supplierdQuantity><ns:SalesOrderReference><ns:DocumentID><ns:ID>5555555555555</ns:ID></ns:DocumentID><ns:LineNumber>5</ns:LineNumber></ns:SalesOrderReference><companycode>1422</companycode><ns:Type>Standard</ns:Type><FulfilmentSourceType>new arrival</FulfilmentSourceType></suppementaryBalance>
</DataArea></TitanBalance>

<TitanBalance releaseID="9999.999" languageCode="en" xmlns="www.titan.com" xmlns:ns="www.titan.org"><ns:ApplicationArea><ns:Sender><ns:LogicalID>ATG</ns:LogicalID><ns:ComponentID>0.0.1.1</ns:ComponentID></ns:Sender><ns:CreationDateTime>2024-05-16T09:26:02.378+02:00</ns:CreationDateTime><ns:DAD>556666660000</ns:DAD></ns:ApplicationArea><DataArea><ns:Process><ns:ActionList><ns:actionFile expressionLanguage="text" actionCode="Modified">supplier</ns:actionFile></ns:ActionList></ns:Process>
<suppementaryBalance><ProductItem><ns:ItemID><ns:ID>000000000101394700</ns:ID></ns:ItemID><ns:UOMCode>EA</ns:UOMCode></ProductItem><ns:supplierdQuantity>2</ns:supplierdQuantity><ns:SalesOrderReference><ns:DocumentID><ns:ID>111111111111111</ns:ID></ns:DocumentID><ns:LineNumber>6</ns:LineNumber></ns:SalesOrderReference><companycode>1422</companycode><ns:Type>Standard</ns:Type><FulfilmentSourceType>new arrival</FulfilmentSourceType></suppementaryBalance>
</DataArea></TitanBalance>

My output should come in one single line as below:
<TitanBalance releaseID="9999.999" languageCode="en" xmlns="www.titan.com" xmlns:ns="www.titan.org"><ns:ApplicationArea><ns:Sender><ns:LogicalID>ATG</ns:LogicalID><ns:ComponentID>0.0.1.1</ns:ComponentID></ns:Sender><ns:CreationDateTime>2024-05-16T09:26:02.378+02:00</ns:CreationDateTime><ns:DAD>556666660000</ns:DAD></ns:ApplicationArea><DataArea><ns:Process><ns:ActionList><ns:actionFile expressionLanguage="text" actionCode="Modified">supplier</ns:actionFile></ns:ActionList></ns:Process><suppementaryBalance><ProductItem><ns:ItemID><ns:ID>000000000101090593</ns:ID></ns:ItemID><ns:UOMCode>EA</ns:UOMCode></ProductItem><ns:supplierdQuantity>1</ns:supplierdQuantity><ns:SalesOrderReference><ns:DocumentID><ns:ID>6666666666666</ns:ID></ns:DocumentID><ns:LineNumber>1</ns:LineNumber></ns:SalesOrderReference><companycode>1488</companycode><ns:Type>Standard</ns:Type><FulfilmentSourceType>new arrival</FulfilmentSourceType></suppementaryBalance></DataArea></TitanBalance>


Your example seems to join all the lines while your title says something else. Can you please [edit] to clarify? Please take care to preserve the formatting (but obviously remove the empty lines if you did not mean for them to be there, etc)

If you want all your output scrunched up onto a single line, just remove the linefeeds tr -d '\n' < YOURFILE

Do you really only want 1 line of output or do you want 6 lines of output, one per block of 3 input lines? Do you really have a blank line between every 3 lines of input or not? Please [edit] your question to show exactly the input you want to parse and exactly the output you need given that input.

sed is great for doing s/old/new on individual lines but for anything more than that just use awk for clarity, simplicity, robustness, efficiency, maintainability, adaptability, portability, etc.
I think this might be what you're trying to do, using any awk and assuming you do have a blank line between each block of 3 lines as shown in the sample input in your question:
$ awk -v RS= -F'\n' -v OFS= '{$1=$1} 1' Titaninput.txt
<TitanBalance releaseID="9999.999" languageCode="en" xmlns="www.titan.com" xmlns:ns="www.titan.org"><ns:ApplicationArea><ns:Sender><ns:LogicalID>ATG</ns:LogicalID><ns:ComponentID>0.0.1.1</ns:ComponentID></ns:Sender><ns:CreationDateTime>2024-05-16T09:26:02.378+02:00</ns:CreationDateTime><ns:DAD>556666660000</ns:DAD></ns:ApplicationArea><DataArea><ns:Process><ns:ActionList><ns:actionFile expressionLanguage="text" actionCode="Modified">supplier</ns:actionFile></ns:ActionList></ns:Process><suppementaryBalance><ProductItem><ns:ItemID><ns:ID>000000000101090593</ns:ID></ns:ItemID><ns:UOMCode>EA</ns:UOMCode></ProductItem><ns:supplierdQuantity>1</ns:supplierdQuantity><ns:SalesOrderReference><ns:DocumentID><ns:ID>6666666666666</ns:ID></ns:DocumentID><ns:LineNumber>1</ns:LineNumber></ns:SalesOrderReference><companycode>1488</companycode><ns:Type>Standard</ns:Type><FulfilmentSourceType>new arrival</FulfilmentSourceType></suppementaryBalance></DataArea></TitanBalance>
<TitanBalance releaseID="9999.999" languageCode="en" xmlns="www.titan.com" xmlns:ns="www.titan.org"><ns:ApplicationArea><ns:Sender><ns:LogicalID>ATG</ns:LogicalID><ns:ComponentID>0.0.1.1</ns:ComponentID></ns:Sender><ns:CreationDateTime>2024-05-16T09:26:02.378+02:00</ns:CreationDateTime><ns:DAD>556666660000</ns:DAD></ns:ApplicationArea><DataArea><ns:Process><ns:ActionList><ns:actionFile expressionLanguage="text" actionCode="Modified">supplier</ns:actionFile></ns:ActionList></ns:Process><suppementaryBalance><ProductItem><ns:ItemID><ns:ID>000000000100007893</ns:ID></ns:ItemID><ns:UOMCode>EA</ns:UOMCode></ProductItem><ns:supplierdQuantity>1</ns:supplierdQuantity><ns:SalesOrderReference><ns:DocumentID><ns:ID>88888888888888</ns:ID></ns:DocumentID><ns:LineNumber>3</ns:LineNumber></ns:SalesOrderReference><companycode>1488</companycode><ns:Type>Standard</ns:Type><FulfilmentSourceType>new arrival</FulfilmentSourceType></suppementaryBalance></DataArea></TitanBalance>
<TitanBalance releaseID="9999.999" languageCode="en" xmlns="www.titan.com" xmlns:ns="www.titan.org"><ns:ApplicationArea><ns:Sender><ns:LogicalID>ATG</ns:LogicalID><ns:ComponentID>0.0.1.1</ns:ComponentID></ns:Sender><ns:CreationDateTime>2024-05-16T09:26:02.378+02:00</ns:CreationDateTime><ns:DAD>556666660000</ns:DAD></ns:ApplicationArea><DataArea><ns:Process><ns:ActionList><ns:actionFile expressionLanguage="text" actionCode="Modified">supplier</ns:actionFile></ns:ActionList></ns:Process><suppementaryBalance><ProductItem><ns:ItemID><ns:ID>000000000100679537</ns:ID></ns:ItemID><ns:UOMCode>EA</ns:UOMCode></ProductItem><ns:supplierdQuantity>100</ns:supplierdQuantity><ns:SalesOrderReference><ns:DocumentID><ns:ID>00000000000</ns:ID></ns:DocumentID><ns:LineNumber>1</ns:LineNumber></ns:SalesOrderReference><companycode>1484</companycode><ns:Type>Standard</ns:Type><FulfilmentSourceType>new arrival</FulfilmentSourceType></suppementaryBalance></DataArea></TitanBalance>
<TitanBalance releaseID="9999.999" languageCode="en" xmlns="www.titan.com" xmlns:ns="www.titan.org"><ns:ApplicationArea><ns:Sender><ns:LogicalID>ATG</ns:LogicalID><ns:ComponentID>0.0.1.1</ns:ComponentID></ns:Sender><ns:CreationDateTime>2024-05-16T09:26:02.378+02:00</ns:CreationDateTime><ns:DAD>556666660000</ns:DAD></ns:ApplicationArea><DataArea><ns:Process><ns:ActionList><ns:actionFile expressionLanguage="text" actionCode="Modified">supplier</ns:actionFile></ns:ActionList></ns:Process><suppementaryBalance><ProductItem><ns:ItemID><ns:ID>000000000100663093</ns:ID></ns:ItemID><ns:UOMCode>EA</ns:UOMCode></ProductItem><ns:supplierdQuantity>19</ns:supplierdQuantity><ns:SalesOrderReference><ns:DocumentID><ns:ID>00000000000000</ns:ID></ns:DocumentID><ns:LineNumber>2</ns:LineNumber></ns:SalesOrderReference><companycode>1484</companycode><ns:Type>Standard</ns:Type><FulfilmentSourceType>new arrival</FulfilmentSourceType></suppementaryBalance></DataArea></TitanBalance>
<TitanBalance releaseID="9999.999" languageCode="en" xmlns="www.titan.com" xmlns:ns="www.titan.org"><ns:ApplicationArea><ns:Sender><ns:LogicalID>ATG</ns:LogicalID><ns:ComponentID>0.0.1.1</ns:ComponentID></ns:Sender><ns:CreationDateTime>2024-05-16T09:26:02.378+02:00</ns:CreationDateTime><ns:DAD>556666660000</ns:DAD></ns:ApplicationArea><DataArea><ns:Process><ns:ActionList><ns:actionFile expressionLanguage="text" actionCode="Modified">supplier</ns:actionFile></ns:ActionList></ns:Process><suppementaryBalance><ProductItem><ns:ItemID><ns:ID>000000000101394699</ns:ID></ns:ItemID><ns:UOMCode>EA</ns:UOMCode></ProductItem><ns:supplierdQuantity>2</ns:supplierdQuantity><ns:SalesOrderReference><ns:DocumentID><ns:ID>5555555555555</ns:ID></ns:DocumentID><ns:LineNumber>5</ns:LineNumber></ns:SalesOrderReference><companycode>1422</companycode><ns:Type>Standard</ns:Type><FulfilmentSourceType>new arrival</FulfilmentSourceType></suppementaryBalance></DataArea></TitanBalance>
<TitanBalance releaseID="9999.999" languageCode="en" xmlns="www.titan.com" xmlns:ns="www.titan.org"><ns:ApplicationArea><ns:Sender><ns:LogicalID>ATG</ns:LogicalID><ns:ComponentID>0.0.1.1</ns:ComponentID></ns:Sender><ns:CreationDateTime>2024-05-16T09:26:02.378+02:00</ns:CreationDateTime><ns:DAD>556666660000</ns:DAD></ns:ApplicationArea><DataArea><ns:Process><ns:ActionList><ns:actionFile expressionLanguage="text" actionCode="Modified">supplier</ns:actionFile></ns:ActionList></ns:Process><suppementaryBalance><ProductItem><ns:ItemID><ns:ID>000000000101394700</ns:ID></ns:ItemID><ns:UOMCode>EA</ns:UOMCode></ProductItem><ns:supplierdQuantity>2</ns:supplierdQuantity><ns:SalesOrderReference><ns:DocumentID><ns:ID>111111111111111</ns:ID></ns:DocumentID><ns:LineNumber>6</ns:LineNumber></ns:SalesOrderReference><companycode>1422</companycode><ns:Type>Standard</ns:Type><FulfilmentSourceType>new arrival</FulfilmentSourceType></suppementaryBalance></DataArea></TitanBalance>

In the above awk command, -v RS= -F'\n' together tell awk to read multi-line records where records are separated by empty lines, and split each record into fields at newlines, then -v OFS= tells awk to use nothing when separating fields for output and {$1=$1} tells awk to reconstruct the current record, replacing all FSs (\ns) with OFSs (nothing). Then 1 is shorhand for {print} to print the current record.
Read the awk man page or the gawk manual for more info:

-v RS= - https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Multiple-Line
-F'\n' - https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Full-Line-Fields
-v OFS= - https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Output-Separators
{$1=$1} - https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Changing-Fields
1 - https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Truth-Values and https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Expression-Patterns.

Alternatively the above can be implemented with just paste:
$ paste -d '\0' - - - - < Titaninput.txt
<TitanBalance releaseID="9999.999" languageCode="en" xmlns="www.titan.com" xmlns:ns="www.titan.org"><ns:ApplicationArea><ns:Sender><ns:LogicalID>ATG</ns:LogicalID><ns:ComponentID>0.0.1.1</ns:ComponentID></ns:Sender><ns:CreationDateTime>2024-05-16T09:26:02.378+02:00</ns:CreationDateTime><ns:DAD>556666660000</ns:DAD></ns:ApplicationArea><DataArea><ns:Process><ns:ActionList><ns:actionFile expressionLanguage="text" actionCode="Modified">supplier</ns:actionFile></ns:ActionList></ns:Process><suppementaryBalance><ProductItem><ns:ItemID><ns:ID>000000000101090593</ns:ID></ns:ItemID><ns:UOMCode>EA</ns:UOMCode></ProductItem><ns:supplierdQuantity>1</ns:supplierdQuantity><ns:SalesOrderReference><ns:DocumentID><ns:ID>6666666666666</ns:ID></ns:DocumentID><ns:LineNumber>1</ns:LineNumber></ns:SalesOrderReference><companycode>1488</companycode><ns:Type>Standard</ns:Type><FulfilmentSourceType>new arrival</FulfilmentSourceType></suppementaryBalance></DataArea></TitanBalance>
<TitanBalance releaseID="9999.999" languageCode="en" xmlns="www.titan.com" xmlns:ns="www.titan.org"><ns:ApplicationArea><ns:Sender><ns:LogicalID>ATG</ns:LogicalID><ns:ComponentID>0.0.1.1</ns:ComponentID></ns:Sender><ns:CreationDateTime>2024-05-16T09:26:02.378+02:00</ns:CreationDateTime><ns:DAD>556666660000</ns:DAD></ns:ApplicationArea><DataArea><ns:Process><ns:ActionList><ns:actionFile expressionLanguage="text" actionCode="Modified">supplier</ns:actionFile></ns:ActionList></ns:Process><suppementaryBalance><ProductItem><ns:ItemID><ns:ID>000000000100007893</ns:ID></ns:ItemID><ns:UOMCode>EA</ns:UOMCode></ProductItem><ns:supplierdQuantity>1</ns:supplierdQuantity><ns:SalesOrderReference><ns:DocumentID><ns:ID>88888888888888</ns:ID></ns:DocumentID><ns:LineNumber>3</ns:LineNumber></ns:SalesOrderReference><companycode>1488</companycode><ns:Type>Standard</ns:Type><FulfilmentSourceType>new arrival</FulfilmentSourceType></suppementaryBalance></DataArea></TitanBalance>
<TitanBalance releaseID="9999.999" languageCode="en" xmlns="www.titan.com" xmlns:ns="www.titan.org"><ns:ApplicationArea><ns:Sender><ns:LogicalID>ATG</ns:LogicalID><ns:ComponentID>0.0.1.1</ns:ComponentID></ns:Sender><ns:CreationDateTime>2024-05-16T09:26:02.378+02:00</ns:CreationDateTime><ns:DAD>556666660000</ns:DAD></ns:ApplicationArea><DataArea><ns:Process><ns:ActionList><ns:actionFile expressionLanguage="text" actionCode="Modified">supplier</ns:actionFile></ns:ActionList></ns:Process><suppementaryBalance><ProductItem><ns:ItemID><ns:ID>000000000100679537</ns:ID></ns:ItemID><ns:UOMCode>EA</ns:UOMCode></ProductItem><ns:supplierdQuantity>100</ns:supplierdQuantity><ns:SalesOrderReference><ns:DocumentID><ns:ID>00000000000</ns:ID></ns:DocumentID><ns:LineNumber>1</ns:LineNumber></ns:SalesOrderReference><companycode>1484</companycode><ns:Type>Standard</ns:Type><FulfilmentSourceType>new arrival</FulfilmentSourceType></suppementaryBalance></DataArea></TitanBalance>
<TitanBalance releaseID="9999.999" languageCode="en" xmlns="www.titan.com" xmlns:ns="www.titan.org"><ns:ApplicationArea><ns:Sender><ns:LogicalID>ATG</ns:LogicalID><ns:ComponentID>0.0.1.1</ns:ComponentID></ns:Sender><ns:CreationDateTime>2024-05-16T09:26:02.378+02:00</ns:CreationDateTime><ns:DAD>556666660000</ns:DAD></ns:ApplicationArea><DataArea><ns:Process><ns:ActionList><ns:actionFile expressionLanguage="text" actionCode="Modified">supplier</ns:actionFile></ns:ActionList></ns:Process><suppementaryBalance><ProductItem><ns:ItemID><ns:ID>000000000100663093</ns:ID></ns:ItemID><ns:UOMCode>EA</ns:UOMCode></ProductItem><ns:supplierdQuantity>19</ns:supplierdQuantity><ns:SalesOrderReference><ns:DocumentID><ns:ID>00000000000000</ns:ID></ns:DocumentID><ns:LineNumber>2</ns:LineNumber></ns:SalesOrderReference><companycode>1484</companycode><ns:Type>Standard</ns:Type><FulfilmentSourceType>new arrival</FulfilmentSourceType></suppementaryBalance></DataArea></TitanBalance>
<TitanBalance releaseID="9999.999" languageCode="en" xmlns="www.titan.com" xmlns:ns="www.titan.org"><ns:ApplicationArea><ns:Sender><ns:LogicalID>ATG</ns:LogicalID><ns:ComponentID>0.0.1.1</ns:ComponentID></ns:Sender><ns:CreationDateTime>2024-05-16T09:26:02.378+02:00</ns:CreationDateTime><ns:DAD>556666660000</ns:DAD></ns:ApplicationArea><DataArea><ns:Process><ns:ActionList><ns:actionFile expressionLanguage="text" actionCode="Modified">supplier</ns:actionFile></ns:ActionList></ns:Process><suppementaryBalance><ProductItem><ns:ItemID><ns:ID>000000000101394699</ns:ID></ns:ItemID><ns:UOMCode>EA</ns:UOMCode></ProductItem><ns:supplierdQuantity>2</ns:supplierdQuantity><ns:SalesOrderReference><ns:DocumentID><ns:ID>5555555555555</ns:ID></ns:DocumentID><ns:LineNumber>5</ns:LineNumber></ns:SalesOrderReference><companycode>1422</companycode><ns:Type>Standard</ns:Type><FulfilmentSourceType>new arrival</FulfilmentSourceType></suppementaryBalance></DataArea></TitanBalance>
<TitanBalance releaseID="9999.999" languageCode="en" xmlns="www.titan.com" xmlns:ns="www.titan.org"><ns:ApplicationArea><ns:Sender><ns:LogicalID>ATG</ns:LogicalID><ns:ComponentID>0.0.1.1</ns:ComponentID></ns:Sender><ns:CreationDateTime>2024-05-16T09:26:02.378+02:00</ns:CreationDateTime><ns:DAD>556666660000</ns:DAD></ns:ApplicationArea><DataArea><ns:Process><ns:ActionList><ns:actionFile expressionLanguage="text" actionCode="Modified">supplier</ns:actionFile></ns:ActionList></ns:Process><suppementaryBalance><ProductItem><ns:ItemID><ns:ID>000000000101394700</ns:ID></ns:ItemID><ns:UOMCode>EA</ns:UOMCode></ProductItem><ns:supplierdQuantity>2</ns:supplierdQuantity><ns:SalesOrderReference><ns:DocumentID><ns:ID>111111111111111</ns:ID></ns:DocumentID><ns:LineNumber>6</ns:LineNumber></ns:SalesOrderReference><companycode>1422</companycode><ns:Type>Standard</ns:Type><FulfilmentSourceType>new arrival</FulfilmentSourceType></suppementaryBalance></DataArea></TitanBalance>

or, if you don't really have a blank line between each block of 3 input lines, then:
$ seq 9 | awk '{printf "%s%s", $0, (NR%3 ? "" : ORS)}'
123
456
789

which can be reduced to:
$ seq 9 | paste -d '\0' - - -
123
456
789

Thanks to @triplee for pointing out that while paste -d '', as I originally had, would work in GNU paste, paste -d '\0' is necessary for portability to all POSIX-compliant awks, including the BSD one on MacOS, and means no separator will be used (not a NUL char will be used) between the concatenated lines, see the POSIX paste spec.

With seq 10 you lose the final newline. My solution, while less succinct, has an END block to fix that.

The paste solution does not have this problem, but the syntax is not entirely portable. On MacOS I need paste -d '\0' - - - (the documentation explains that this represents an empty string, not actually a null character, but it's kind of unintuitive even if you know that).

I've got to believe the OPs input is always in blocks of 3 lines and so there will never be input such as seq 10 would output. If there could be then the OP hasn't told us how that should be handled. (join pairs of lines sometimes?). Thanks for the tip on paste, I updated my answer.

Fair, but I guess good to mention in a comment for the benefit of future visitors who might not have that constraint with their data.

@tripleee I updated my answer to explain why the -d '\0' is there but I'm not sure what I'd say about input that doesn't have 3 lines per record as I just don't know how that should be handled - print the last incomplete block with a newline at the end? print it without a newline at the end? discard it? merge some other number of lines? something else? It's not obvious that printing a newline at the end would always be the right thing to do, it really would be a different question (or questions) with whatever the OP wanted to do stated there and I don't want to discuss all of that here.

I'm just going to leave it as-is and if anyone ever posts a comment asking how to handle that case then I'll tell them to ask a new question with their requirements and [mcve] for that.

Another solution using paste seq 9 | paste -sd'\0\0\n'

What exactly this option do  RS= -F'\n' ?

@purushottamkumar together they tell awk to read multi-line records where records are separated by empty lines, and split each record into fields at newlines. I added an explanation of each construct that first awk command is using to my answer.

If you want a less write-only language than sed, try Awk.
awk '(NR%3 != 0) { printf "%s", $0; next } 1
  END { if (NR % 3 != 0) print "" }' file

In so many words, if the line number is not an even factor of three, print without a newline; otherwise, fall back to the default, which is to print with a newline. (Just NR%3 would be equivalent to (NR%3 != 0) but I felt I wanted to spell it out.) Finally, the END block takes care of adding a final newline if we didn't already print one.
Output with the data from Alp's answer:
onetwothree
fourfivesix
seveneightnine
teneleventwelve
thirteenfourteenfifteen
sixteenseventeeneighteen
nineteentwenty

If you want to join every group of four lines but omit the last one from the group, that's not a very big modification.
awk 'NR%4 { printf "%s", $0; next } 
  { print "" }
  END { if (NR%4) print "" }' file

This time I omitted the != 0 for succinctness.

Updated Answer
Use awk to split on blank lines:
awk -v RS= '$1=$1' YOURFILE

Original Answer
A slightly different approach, effectively removing single linefeeds and only leaving double ones:

transliterate newlines into pipe symbols (|)
delete all instances of pipe symbols that are not followed by another pipe symbol - these will occur at ends of lines 1 and 2
transliterate pipe symbols back into newlines


tr '\n' '|' < YOURFILE | sed 's/|[^|]//g' | tr '|' '\n'


It's unlikely given the sample input the OP showed but that awk command would fail if the first field of any input record evaluated to 0, e.g. try printf '0foo bar\n' | awk -v RS= '{$1=$1}' and you'll see it produces no output. Never use an action in a conditional context unless you need the result of that action to be evaluated as a condition to avoid problems like this which usually only bite you in the ass 6 months after your code hits the customer's data and it contains a case you didn't think to test! Always do {$1=$1} 1 in a situation like this instead.

The first tr, tr '\n' '|' < YOURFILE, produces output that's no longer a valid POSIX text file and so YMMV with what any subsequent tool does with it, the sed command would need to be sed 's/|\([^|]\)/\1/g' or similar to avoid deleting the first char of each input line, and the general approach would obviously fail if the input contained any | characters as the final tr would convert them all to newlines.

Back on that first awk command - if you don't also add the FS and OFS settings I used in my answer then as well as the newlines, any other chains of white space in the input, including multiple tabs and/or blanks, will be converted to blank chars, and the lines will be joined with blanks between them rather than nothing between them as in the expected output.

@EdMorton Thank you for sharing your insights. I have upvoted your answer as the preferable option.

This might work for you (GNU sed):
sed -n '/\S/H;//b;x;s/\n//gp' file

If a line contains text, append it to the hold space.
If a line contains text, do no further processing.
Otherwise, swap to the hold space, remove all newlines and print the result.
If the last line of the file may or may not contain a blank line, use:
sed -n '/\S/H;$s/.*//;/\S/b;x;s/\n//gp' file

N.B. This joins all consecutive lines that contain text.
If the format is 3 lines of text and a blank line, a simpler alternative is:
sed -n 'N;N;s/\n//gp;n' file

Or to retain the space line:
sed 'N;N;s/\n//g;n' file

Alternative using paste:
paste -sd'\0\0\0\n' file

